# (UNterrminated String Literal)how to print received json data in dropdown list in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to put a dropdown list for received json data but i m getting below error.please help me on this.i' m not able to figure out what causing the below erroe.it has to print all the values in drop down list.

and the values looks like below.

```
[{"sno":1,"listOfOperators":"Jio"}
{"sno":2,"listOfOperators":"Airtel"},
{"sno":3,"listOfOperators":"Docomo"},
{"sno":4,"listOfOperators":"Ides"},
{"sno":5,"listOfOperators":"Vodacom"},
{"sno":6,"listOfOperators":"Vodafone"}]
```

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal

Please find below code  for causing above error

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<title>Operators</title>




      <script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              dataType : 'json'',
              contentType : "application/json",
               url : "${home}getOPList",
              cache: false,
              success: function(response){
             var str = JSON.stringify(response);
             var operatorList;
                 alert("yes");
                 alert(str);
                 alert(response);

                 for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ )
                 {
                   console.log(response[i].listOfOperators);
                   operatorList +="<option value = ' "
                   +response[i].sno+
                   " ' >"
                   + response[i].listOfOperators +
                   "</option>"

                 }
                 $('#opList').html(operatorList);

          },
              error: function(){
               alert('Error while request..');
              }
             });
});


</script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="op-block">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Please Select an Operator</h1>
      <select id="opList">
           <option value =' '></option>
      </select>

    </div>
            </body>
  </html>
```

please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

After making sure your `response` is valid, you should loop through it so:

```js
    var response = [
      {"sno":1,"listOfOperators":"Jio"},
      {"sno":2,"listOfOperators":"Airtel"},
      {"sno":3,"listOfOperators":"Docomo"},
      {"sno":4,"listOfOperators":"Ides"},
      {"sno":5,"listOfOperators":"Vodacom"},
      {"sno":6,"listOfOperators":"Vodafone"}
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++ )
    {
      console.log(response[i]);
    }
```

Comment: I tried above code it is printing in console , but when i try with alert box a popup is coming like [object ,Object]

Comment: however my requirement is to print the listOfOperators values in dropdownlistt.plese help me on this and select id as opList

Comment: If you alert(response[i]) then you will see an object, you need to stringify it to see it in an alert... More importantly, you should be now looping through your data and creating your dropdown.